# Xcode make iad sticks to bottom of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can I make that iad banner is always in bottom of the screen, user can scroll up and down but the add will be there(bottom of the screen) always. This is my code that I use for iad:

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

**ViewController.m**

```
// Method is called when the iAd is loaded.
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

    // Creates animation.
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    // Sets the duration of the animation to 1.
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    // Sets the alpha to 1.
        [banner setAlpha:1];

    //  Performs animation.
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

// Method is called when the iAd fails to load.
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

    // Creates animation.
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    // Sets the duration of the animation to 1.
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    // Sets the alpha to 0.
       [banner setAlpha:0];

    //  Performs animation.
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: I have implemented a neat solution for this specific problem while developing one of my apps. If you'd like to contact me on https://www.codementor.io/francesco, I'd be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your AppDelegate's window and put all your views above that banner. i.e. decrease height with banner height for all ViewControllers.

Comment: What do you mean "decrease height with banner height for all ViewControllers" ?

Comment: Lets you have a banner of 60px at bottom. And you add this to your appDelegate's window as subview. Now if your firstViewController (Lets say it's list of students) should have height of (screenHeight - statusBarHeight - adBannerHeight) otherwise views will overlap and adBanner or a portion from your viewCongroller will be hidden